# Which annotation tag should use to get repeatable tag content in JaxB?

Tags: java, jaxb

Which annotation tag should use to store paragraph element contents in a String Array?  Since there are no elements inside the paragraph, it is not possible to store content even by creating a separate paragraph class.

```xml
<letter>
    <from>Hansel</from>
    <to>Gretal</to>
    <paragraphs>
        <paragraph>
            First paragraph text
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph>
            Seconds paragraph text
        </paragraph>
    </paragraphs>
</letter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use @XmlElementWrapper:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html.

Like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "paragraphs")
@XmlElement(name = "paragraph")
String[] paragraphs;
```

See also this for an example:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.cubeisland/messageextractor-core/2.0.0/de/cubeisland/messageextractor/extractor/java/configuration/Annotation.java#82